# How rare would a set of bags of holding/portable holes that share the same interior space be?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew

What would the rarity for a set of bags of holding and similar items like portable hole, that share the same extra dimensional space? It would be similar to how ender chests work in Minecraft, or piggy banks in terraria.

The source item (Bag of Holding/Portable Hole) would work exactly like they normally do, but each source item would have access to the same interior space and work at any range, including across planes.

Comment: For clarity, are you asking about multiple items that share the same space, where a character in one location could deposit an item, and a character in a second location could retrieve it?

Comment: This question might be answerable under the principles of [Good Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), but you need to provide a lot more information about the parameters of this item. What's its carrying capacity? Does it have a maximum range, or inability to function across planes? Is its weight independent of the weight of the objects it contains? Does it have restrictions on how quickly items may be retrieved from it? Providing these details will make this question a lot better.

Comment: Exactly, there would be ‘multiple’ of the items that one person could place an item in, then another could take it out. In the case of a set of bags of holding, it would be the inner space, with multiple openings to the various bags.

Comment: In particular, a good idea might be to edit in a semi-official statblock into the question describing the features and limitations of this item. That would be a very good step towards getting good answers to this question.

Comment: It acts exactly like the normal items, but you can access it from multiple places, it can work across planes, and at any range

Comment: What does "like the normal items" mean in this context? The *Portable Hole* is a very different object than a *Bag of Holding* or a *Heward's Handy Haversack*, which seem more like the kind of items you're trying to modify, and it's not clear from context what the comparison to a *Portable Hole* is meant to evoke.

Comment: They for all intents and purposes are those items, but the inventories can be accessed from any existing part of the set

Comment: I have a feeling this question will trend to being closed because you haven't added the full stat block. It may help in your future posts (and this one) to make sure you fully flesh out the item, provide the stat block, a rating you think, and why you came up with it - and then ask for verification on it. Or no rating, and provide why you couldn't figure it out. Otherwise, you may get downvotes for not doing enough of your own research prior to posting.

Comment: How would I add the stat block?

Comment: You'd make one :) You can do it within a quote, but use the formatting for items that the DMG has. You've basically created a magic item and it should 'look' the same in terms of stat block information as an existing item. [Example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136498/what-should-the-rarity-rating-be-for-this-homebrew-healing-brick)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Very-Rare, *maybe* Rare depending on the properties of the item itself

With the release of the *Unearthed Arcana: Revised Artificer* class, Wizards of the Coast introduced the ability for an Artificer to create an item that functions incredibly similarly to how you've specified this object, though weaker:

> #### Many-Handed Pouch
>
> Prerequisite: 4th-level artificer
>   Item: 2–5 pouches
>
> The   infused pouches all share   one interdimensional    space of    the same    capacity    as  a   single  pouch. Thus,    reaching    into    any of  the pouches allows  access  to  the same    storage space.
>
> A pouch   operates as long    as  it is within    100 miles   of  another one of  the pouches;    the pouch   is  otherwise   empty and   won’t   accept  any contents.
>
> If    this    infusion    ends,   the items   stored  in  the shared  space   move    into    one of  the pouches,    determined  at  random. The rest of the pouches become  empty.
>
> —[Unearthed Arcana, Revised Artificer, 2019-02-28](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf)

Note the prerequisite: a 4th level Artificer. This suggests that as-is, the item described by this feature represents a Common or Uncommon quality item, since the Dungeon Master's Guide specifies the rarity for homebrew items to range around Common at level 3 and Uncommon at level 6.

However, there are a couple of major advantages to the item you've described over the item described in the Unearthed Arcana:

- It has a much larger carrying capacity (500lbs for a Bag of Holding, vs 6lbs for a Pouch, 64ft<sup>3</sup> volume vs 1/5ft<sup>3</sup>
- It can be used at any range, with no limit on being on the same plane (the Many-Handed Pouch has a range limit of 100 miles and cannot be used on different dimensions)
- It can be used by anyone, whereas the Many-Handed Pouch requires at least a friendly Artificer to create the object for them and maintain the Infusion's magic

Because of these advantages, I'd bump up the rarity on this item to at least Rare, and probably Very-Rare. That puts it well above the *Bag of Holding*'s rarity and the [relatively deduced] rarity of this item available to the Artificer class.

Comment: A bigger consideration is that due to size it allows a person to use it as transport which is a big deal.

Answer (score 24):

## Legendary

This is basically a portable and resourceless sending/teleport/plane shift/gate pair of items. The utility of this is massive both in terms of movement and communication.

The primary factors that increase the rating to this level are the planar transfer abilities and the ability to move creatures massive distances. The closest spell that can do this is Gate, which is a 9th level spell and would be a Legendary level scroll that can only be used once. By making this at-will, the item has Legendary status.

### Not all Legendary items are combat focused

In fact, there is a Legendary item, the [Cubic Gate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/cubic-gate), that functions very similarly to what this paired/shared item can do:

> You can use an action to press one side of the cube to cast the gate spell with it, opening a portal to the plane keyed to that side. Alternatively, if you use an action to press one side twice, you can cast the plane shift spell (save DC 17) with the cube and transport the targets to the plane keyed to that side.

Do note that this Legendary item has limited uses. Although it does allow the actual *plane shift* spell, which could be considered combat, that isn't it's only function or ability.

There are other Legendary items that are also Utility focused: [Sovereign Glue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sovereign-glue) and it's compatriot, [Universal Solvent](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/universal-solvent).

### Addressing the similarity to *[Many Handed Pouch](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf)*

The release of this Unearthed Arcana brings another item into review. However, it's important to note that this is still Unearthed Arcana and has not yet passed balanced review in general. But the item is different enough from the proposed similarity for the following reasons:

1. **Storage Capacity** The UA item has an undefined capacity and only states that they all must have the same. It is unclear if they considered "pouch" to be of equal size as a haversack, bag of holding, or portable hole - but my hunch is that they consider pouch to be much smaller. They could be referencing a standard [pouch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/pouch), but it's unclear.

   > A cloth or leather pouch can hold 1/5 cubic foot/ 6 pounds of gear - or up to 20 sling bullets or 50 blowgun needles, among other things. A compartmentalized pouch for holding spell components is called a component pouch.
2. **Range limitations**. Limiting the range to 100 miles of another pouch and not allowing planar transfer is a major nerf compared to that of the proposed item. This along signifies a major power increase/decrease.

These two factors are significant nerfs to the proposed item and actually support my rating of the proposed item as Legendary.

Comment: If it was small enough that only, say, a few coins or a piece of paper could pass through, and it only worked on one plane, then I would downgrade the rarity to Very Rare. But this is absolutely game-changing as written -- pay a hireling to monitor the other end, and dump an entire treasure horde into it. Get the party's gnome to jump in and get pulled out from the other bag. Plus, once you get into magic that goes across planes, you're in a whole other world. Other caveats that can bring down the rarity would be charges and size limits.

Comment: +1 You could have said it was Uber-Legendary, given that it could be game-wrecking even for 17th-20th level chars who already posses legendary items.

Comment: DnD is a very combat oriented RPG. This item is not that useful in combat, so I would rate it lower.

Comment: @JohnMickey Open up both bags, teleport one into space and watch the whole atmosphere of the planet get sucked away!

Comment: @András I addressed your combat concern.

Comment: @Suthek I assume with these things (gates, portable holes, etc) that atmosphere does not pass through -- only things forced through them actually are.